# How to determine the limits of object transformations

Tags: graphics, 3d, linear-algebra, transformation, vector-graphics

Let's say, for example, that we have a cubic Bezier curve in a bounded Cartesian space, where x ranges from 0 to 500, and y ranges from 0 to 300:

[image]

And I want to manipulate this curve with scale, rotation, and translation matrices, with the limitations that I do not want any point on this curve to step outside the 500x300 grid.

Given this curve, is there a way to compute (EDIT: i.e. predict) limits to the scale, rotation, and translation parameters *a priori* such that the resulting transformations to the curve will never cause it to step outside this grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the bounding box of the curve and then apply the transformations to the box to see when it goes out of range. Just iterate through the curve to find the bounding box.

[image: fig]

Comment: This would definitely simplify things. But is there a way to efficiently compute when the box will go out of range without applying transformations in a brute force manner?

Comment: You only need to track 4 points to see which one might go out of bounds. That is going to be efficient. Each point is a matrix-vector product to compute.